# how to loop over data feeded with a placeholder in tensorflow only one time using the new Dataset API

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am starting to use the new dataset API and one thing that I want to do is not described on the doc (https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#training_workflows)

My data fit in memory so I want load it in tensorflow to make the training efficient and for this I see for now 2 way to do it:

one is loading the data in the graph directly like this:

```
dataset = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, Y))
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

# loop on epochs
for _ in range(5):
    # Initialize an iterator over the training dataset.
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    # loop over all the batch
    for _ in range(1000):
        s = time.time()
        try:
            sess.run(next_element)
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print("Finish epoch")
```

the other one is to load the data in a placeholder so the data is not save in the graph:

```
features_placeholder = tf.placeholder(features.dtype, features.shape)
labels_placeholder = tf.placeholder(labels.dtype, labels.shape)

dataset = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features_placeholder, labels_placeholder))
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

# loop on epochs
for _ in range(5):
    # Initialize an iterator over the training dataset.
    sess.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict={features_placeholder: X, labels_placeholder: Y})
    # loop over all the batch
    for _ in range(1000):
        s = time.time()
        try:
            sess.run(next_element)
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print("Finish epoch")
```

The second is I think the best to save memory, but I don't want to feed the data at each epoch. It is really a loss of performance for nothing.

Is there a way to initialize the iterator only one time with a placeholder?

something like this:

```
sess.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict={features_placeholder: X, labels_placeholder: Y})

# loop on epochs
for _ in range(5):
    # Initialize an iterator over the training dataset.
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    # loop over all the batch
    for _ in range(1000):
        s = time.time()
        try:
            sess.run(next_element)
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print("Finish epoch")
```

That way we can keep the performance of the first solution and saving memory like the second solution.

> Note:
>
> one solution is to define the number of epoch with `dataset.repeat()`
>   method but with it we kind of loose track of where we are in the
>   training.
>
> I want to check after each epoch (one pass over all the data) the
>   evolution of the loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would recommend quantifying the performance overhead of feeding `X` and `Y` each time you initialize the iterator. For primitive types like `tf.int32` and `tf.float32` it is often possible to feed a value without copying any data, and in that case the overhead will be negligible. Even if a copy is necessary, it will entail a single `memcpy()`, which can be surprisingly fast. (On the other hand, feeding a `tf.string` tensor can be more expensive, because it requires multiple small copies to convert between the Python and C++ string representations.)

Assuming that it is a significant overhead, you can make it a one-time cost by storing the input data in a `tf.Variable`. For example:

```
placeholder_X = tf.placeholder(X.dtype, X.shape)
var_X = tf.Variable(placeholder_X)
placeholder_Y = tf.placeholder(Y.dtype, Y.shape)
var_Y = tf.Variable(placeholder_Y)

dataset = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((var_X, var_Y))
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

# ...

# The contents of `X` and `Y` will be copied once, in this call.
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer(), feed_dict={
    placeholder_X: X, placeholder_Y = Y})

for _ in range(5):
  # The iterator will be initialized from the variables with no copy.
  sess.run(iterator.initializer)

  # ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The doc says that feeding data directly with `Dataset.from_tensor_slices` will save it as a `tf.constant` thus creating a waste of memory. So what changes in term of memory by saving it in a `tf.Variable`?

Comment: The `tf.constant()` op was originally designed for small constants (like scalars and shapes), and so the runtime usually stores multiple different copies of it for convenience. By contrast, variables are expected to be large, and TensorFlow will only store a single copy of them by default.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to initialise at every epoch. You can do it once before the training loop. But you also need to tell the data set to repeat and reshuffle at each iteration when you are defining the dataset:

```
features_placeholder = tf.placeholder(features.dtype, features.shape)
labels_placeholder = tf.placeholder(labels.dtype, labels.shape)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features_placeholder, labels_placeholder)).shuffle(buffer_value,reshuffle_each_iteration=True).repeat().batch(batch_num)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

#Initialize an iterator over the training dataset.
sess.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict={features_placeholder: X, labels_placeholder: Y})
    # loop on epochs
for _ in range(5):
    # loop over all the batch
    for _ in range(1000):
        s = time.time()
        sess.run(next_element)
```

Note that since the repeat is on, you need to compute the exact number of iterations that you need to loop over data once in each epoch and set it in your inner loop.

Comment: the thing is that when you use repeat I think it will fill the batch completely even if the dataset is not a multiple, so there is the risk to get some data appearing 2 times

Comment: True, but if your batch size is not too big, iterating over some few data points twice in one iteration may not cause much problem I guess...